# Additional modifier keys in emacs?

Tags: emacs, customization, key-bindings

I have been modifying my Emacs setup quite alot recently but I reached a problem which is starting to annoy me. I would like to be able to introduce additional modifier like keys. What I am trying to do, to make things clearer, is when I am in dired-mode (which doesn't accept textual input so normal letters can be rebound) I would like it so that when I hold down the letter `s` and press `j` or `l` the cursor moves to the next and previous directory line respectively. Effectively making the `s` key act like a modifier.

I have looked into making the `s` apply a modifier such as `super` or `hyper` but those are all used for global things. Is this possible? if not then that's a shame.

Edit:

There seems to be some confusion with what I'm after. If I define a normal key sequence such as

`(define-key map (kbd "s j") 'dired-next-dirline)`

Then I have to keep pressing the `s` key *every time* before I press `j` to move to the next directory line. This is **not** what I am looking for (not to sound angry :P) I want `s` to act like a modifier where I can keep the `s` key *held* down and keep tapping `j` to move down the lines.

I hope I have made this more clear. Thanks.

Comment: My understanding is that adding a genuine modifier key to use in Emacs is an OS-level process. That's no use to you, as you only want it to act as such in certain Emacs contexts. So AFAIK, what you're asking for cannot be done at present.

Comment: It's possible to have a command temporarily change the keymap, so that you only need to repeat the last key in the key sequence. `C-x e` (execute macro) does this - to repeat the macro, just hit `e` again.  The source code for `kmacro-call-macro` seems to be the place to start reading...

Comment: @legoscia I like the idea of changing the keymap temporarily however I think using macros is a little unnecessary. If no one comes up with a better idea you might want to post that as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug around in the code and came up with this.  It binds `s j` to `my-dired-next-dirline`, but right after you've done that, just `j` is enough to do it again.  Any other key resets the temporary binding.

Note that the function `set-temporary-overlay-map` was added in Emacs 24.2, which at the time of this writing hasn't been released yet, so you'll need to build [Emacs from git](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsFromGit).

```
(defun my-dired-next-dirline ()
  (interactive)
  (dired-next-dirline 1)
  (set-temporary-overlay-map
   (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key map [?j] 'my-dired-next-dirline)
     map)
   nil))

(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(progn
     (let ((prefix-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key prefix-map "j" 'my-dired-next-dirline)  
       (define-key dired-mode-map "s" prefix-map))))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Key chords](http://www.emacswiki.org/KeyChord) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this isn't what i'm looking for since I would have to keep pressing `s` every time I wish to use it as   a modifier.

Comment: Don't you have to press shift or other modifiers every time when you want to use them as a modifier?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm probably not very clear. I would like to keep it held down and not have to keep pressing the key to use it as a modifier.

Answer (score 2):

This question pre-dates it, but the Hydra package allows you to do this and more.

https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra

See examples here: https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/blob/master/hydra-examples.el and here https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/blob/master/hydra-test.el

Wiki also has more useful examples https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki/Hydras-by-Topic

Hydra originally only had a rather opaque metaphorical syntax, which made it quite difficult to get started with.  I'm not sure why such a bizarre double-layer of metaphors from colors to mythical stories and monsters with many heads being "vanquished" was used to describe features which are essentially:

- do action and remain in the key-mode (effectively what you're asking for.) (a so called `blue` hydra)
- do action and quit the key-mode (a `red` hydra)

and so on.

Thankfully a more literal syntax was added in Feb 2015, inspect the tests to see the color and literal syntax side by side. (also this commit https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/commit/0a3cc60f5856eb4a38204b9075d67d058ba56bef)

See also this article by the author. http://oremacs.com/2015/02/02/colorful-hydrae/

Answer (score 1):

If key chords is not what you are looking for (as you suggested on a comment to [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939314/391315)), then you seem to want a simple `define-key` that uses a key sequence. i.e.

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "s j") 'dired-previous-line)
```

This has the disadvantage of disabling the original functionality of the `s` key, but you can rebind that to the sequence `s`-`s`, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this is the same sort of answer as the other. I've edited my question to make it more clear I hope you can help me.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your comment to Tom's answer. I did a little digging around, and it looks like it is either very difficult or impossible to treat a normal key as a modifier key. In fact, under certain circumstances, such as a remote terminal situation, it is technically not possible to see if a key is still pressed. legoscia's comment is probably your best bet.

Comment: It does seem to be difficult. I'm thinking of using the temporary keymap solution, it could also come in handy in other areas as well. Anyways thanks for your help its much appreciated.